# Why is it not object destructuring when calling useActionData() in react router dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, destructuring

When I call useActionData(), I don't get any object destruction. When I print to the console, I get name: 'isakGo'. The code looks like this

```
export async function action({request}) {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const name = { name: formData.get("name") }
  return { name };
}

export default function FormTest() {
  const { name } = useActionData(); // error has occured here

  // other codes
}
```

We're creating a router with createBrowserRouter() and serving it with RouterBrowser.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/FormTest",
        element: <FormTest />,
        action: formTestAction,
      }
    ]
  },
])
```

The following error occurs.

> Cannot destructure property 'name' of '(0 , react_router_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useActionData)(...)' as it is undefined.

If you change your code to one that doesn't do object destruction, it will work cleanly.

```
export async function action({request}) {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const name = { name: formData.get("name") }
  return name;
}

export default function FormTest() {
  const name = useActionData(); 

  // other codes
}
```

When I write something like loader() in react router dom, i.e. `const { name } = useLoaderData();`, it works fine. action() is not destroying the object. what am I missing?

I'm using the create-react-app and the react-router-dom@6.11.2 version.

#### Edit

We found additional factors that may be directly related to the error.

1. useActionData() is called when FormTest() is loaded, so the empty name variable is empty.
2. for some reason, it is called 4 times when I print the results to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-action-data)

> This hook provides the returned value from the previous navigation's action result, or undefined if there was no submission.

```js
function SomeComponent() {
  let actionData = useActionData();
  // ...
}
```

> The most common use-case for this hook is form validation errors. If the form isn't right, you can return the errors and let the user try again:

### Code Example

```js
import {
  useActionData,
  Form,
  redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function SignUp() {
  const errors = useActionData();

  return (
    <Form method="post">
      <p>
        <input type="text" name="email" />
        {errors?.email && <span>{errors.email}</span>}
      </p>

      <p>
        <input type="text" name="password" />
        {errors?.password && <span>{errors.password}</span>}
      </p>

      <p>
        <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
      </p>
    </Form>
  );
}

export async function action({ request }) {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const email = formData.get("email");
  const password = formData.get("password");
  const errors = {};

  // validate the fields
  if (typeof email !== "string" || !email.includes("@")) {
    errors.email =
      "That doesn't look like an email address";
  }

  if (typeof password !== "string" || password.length < 6) {
    errors.password = "Password must be > 6 characters";
  }

  // return data if we have errors
  if (Object.keys(errors).length) {
    return errors;
  }

  // otherwise create the user and redirect
  await createUser(email, password);
  return redirect("/dashboard");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't answer my question.

Comment: @isakgo_ I disagree. Even though it's a copy/paste of the official docs, it is my opinion this perfectly answers your question as to why the destructuring fails. Can you clarify what is insufficient?

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks, I think OP misunderstands the usage of this hook.

Comment: @DrewReese Is the destructuring failing because the useActionData() hook returns undefined when it works on initial loading? If so, I'm sure I've misunderstood.

Comment: @isakgo_ Yes, you can't destructure from undefined references.